# Read Specified Cells from the Excel and insert into SQL table

Tags: asp.net

I have an Execl Sheet (2007) in the following structure.
In the Excel sheet `Sno.,Details, State1, State2,Name,College,Address,Department`
are headings

```
--------------------------------------------
Sno. | DETAILS | STATE1 | STATE2
--------------------------------------------
1    | NAME | John | Peter

2    | COLLEGE | AAA | BBB

3    | ADDRESS | YY | ZZ 

4    | DEPARTMENT | IT | ECE
```

I want to insert `STATE1,STATE2` into my database.

Could you please provide table structure for the following excel and
Code to select only `STATE1,STATE2` Column and insert `STATE1,STATE2` colunm details into the database?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example. Change your field accordingly.

```
   var myConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\Language_Batch1_OneClick.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"); ;
    var myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    var upCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    int i = 0;
    try
    {

        string sql = null;
        myConnection.Open();
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        sql = "select STATE1,STATE2 from [sheet-name]";
        myCommand.CommandText = sql;
        var dataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var langText = dataReader["STATE1"].ToString();
            var ansCode = dataReader["STATE2 "].ToString();
            //call your function here update /insert to your database
        }
}
```